# Syntax for covariance generic out parameters when translating C# to F#

Tags: generics, f#, type-parameter

I am converting some old C# code to our F# project and this goes pretty well and smooth, except that I have an interface type that is defined in C# as with a `out T` generic type constraint, and as [TeaDrivenDev](https://stackoverflow.com/users/236507/teadrivendev) points out, this [makes the type covariance](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd469487.aspx):

```
public interface IFoo<out T>
    where T: IBar
{
    T Copy();
}
```

How can this be translated into F#? [If at all?](https://fsharpforfunandprofit.com/posts/completeness-anything-csharp-can-do/) (see edit history for my earlier attempts in code, but TeaDrivenDev has shown me that they were futile and unrelated, based on misunderstanding C#'s `out`).

Comment: I'm not sure I'm getting everything here, but `out` in C# generic type parameters has to do with co-/contravariance (which F# doesn't support, as far as I know), and is entirely unrelated to `out` parameters in the sense of by-reference passing.

Comment: `out` is a contextual keyword in C# that has two unrelated meanings. The `out` generic modifier for covariance that you have encountered in your code is documented here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd469487.aspx

Comment: Ouch, mea culpa. I wasn't aware of that. That's what you get if you have your head in F# for too long, my C# gets rusty. You are totally right. Ok, I should update my question on the covariance thing. Thanks for keeping me honest :).

Comment: There are an suggestion of making it a part of f# and some discussions related to it at
https://fslang.uservoice.com/forums/245727-f-language/suggestions/5663470-provide-covariance-contravariance-language-support    I think this might be related.

Comment: How many places in your codebase would be affected?  Is it too much code to add some explicit casts?  (I suspect the feature usage is so rare that it took a few language revisions before it was added to C# compiler.)

Comment: If it's a big deal, then maybe a little rewrite is in order: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Covariance_and_contravariance_(computer_science)#Function_types

Comment: @GregC: I have meanwhile refactored the OO hierarchy. Some existing code is now failing (couple of 100 tests all indicate cast-related exceptions), shouldn't be too hard to fix.

Comment: @HelgeReneUrholm, interesting, I read it, tx. I guess that should be the answer: "maybe" it will be added to the language, but it isn't there yet.